# JavaScript Slider That Auto Resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a content slider for a client that displays their last four posts. Right now it's just plain HTML but I'm having a problem.

The slider box needs to be 180px high with a scrollbar when necessary. My slider seems to work except it makes the slide boxes all as tall as the tallest box. That leaves short posts with a ton of blank space under them.

Anyone know a fix?

http://jsfiddle.net/insitedesignlab/kQDcb/1/

I've seen that [Quovolver](http://sandbox.sebnitu.com/jquery/quovolver/) does this, but I'd love to know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is #slidesContainer needs to be dynamically resized in order for it's parent to know how long to scroll for. One way to solve the problem is to change your animate call to include a callback:

```
$('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
   },null,null,
   function(){ 
      $('#slidesContainer').css('height', $(this).children(".slide:nth-child(" + parseInt((Math.ceil(-1*slideWidth*(-currentPosition) / $("#slideshow").width())) + 1) + ")").height() + "px"); 
   }
);
```

There's probably a slightly better way to make that calculation, but this will work. You could alternatively hide all the other .slide divs that are not being displayed. Then #slidesContainer will auto-resize to only the visible (not display:none) slide.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been pounding my head all day trying to get this done. Awesome =)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code here [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQDcb/29/). You need to remove the min-height property and set the background color to the slide div.

Comment: That did work but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. Like in the other answer I want the min height to stay there so I can add a y scroll bar if necessary. Thanks though!